# How to speed up multiple clicks in sikuli?

Tags: click, sikuli

I was working on a Sikuli script that uses click action on the same image. I used for loop for that. It works fine, but there is a lag between every click. How to resolve it. 
If anyone has faced this problem and has a solution to it, kindly respond.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The smaller the region that needs to be searched, the faster the image is found and clicked. In my code below I have an example of two methods how sikuli can search for an image and click on it.

Black: Click 3 times on a image. 
Green: Define a region where the image is located.

- Example "Black": This one will be the slowest, becasue for every click we are looking through the whole screen for the image again. And that for all 3 times.
- Example "Green": We locate the image and select that region. Then we are going to search for the image in that region. And that every 3 times.

Also, the bigger you screen the more time it will take to find an image.

Time it takes on my screen: 
 - Black: 3.03646525 seconds 
 - Green: 2.189903776 seconds

Example code: 
(Sikuli with Python)

```
import time
class Pink():
    def __init__(self):
        t0 = time.clock()
        self.Black()
        t1 = time.clock()
        self.Green()
        t2 = time.clock()

        # Time passed.
        timeBlack = (t1 - t0)
        timeGreen = (t2 - t1)
        print('Time in seconds:')
        print(timeBlack)
        print(timeGreen)

    # Click 3 times without region. 
    def Black(self):
        # Find image and click 3 times on image.
        icon = find("image.png")
        click("image.png")
        click("image.png")
        click("image.png")

    # Click 3 times with region.
    def Green(self):
        RegionClick = find("image.png").nearby(5)

        RegionClick.click("image.png")
        RegionClick.click("image.png")
        RegionClick.click("image.png")

# Run class
Pink()
```

What even might be faster is look if a image exits in a certain region, and then clcik on it 3 times. By making use of an loop. If exists .....: click.